# Google Analytics on Ajax based website

Tags: jquery

I've been reading about setting up Google Analytics on an AJAX site and I just wanted to try to confirm I'm implemented it correctly.

On the main page (that holds the AJAX DIV's - in this case) I have the STD Google Analytics Code at the bottom of the page (for load speed) being:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxxxx']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async =      true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +     '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga,   s);
    })();
</script>
```

Then when a user clicks on a link that will load an AJAX `div` (could be called page) like:

```
www.domainname.com\#home
```

This kicks off an AJAX `.load()`. Actually before the `.load()` occurs I have included this extra line of JS (diff end value/page name for each AJAX page/div):

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/home']);
```

Is that it? Is it ok to run the above code before the AJAX `.load()`? Is there a way to check its working by check the site? Or do I need to wait to see if Google Analytics starts to pick up extra pages etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an explanation about how to test google analytics

http://www.webanalyticsworld.net/2010/03/test-google-analytics-without-waiting.html

Comment: The links from that video can be found on the Analytics Blogspot page: http://analytics.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/web-analytics-tv-7-with-avinash-and.html